# armv6 and Entitlements error on App Store Upload

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile, armv7, armv6

I am trying to upload an app via xcode. This app is nearly identical to many other apps I have updated or uploaded recently, using the same Provisioning Profile, so that and the signature shouldn't be a problem. I also don't have any Entitlements in the project, nor are they enabled or pointed to in the Build Settings. I believe I have confirmed every Build Setting, as suggested on the many threads on this topic, but still, no luck. In addition, I have both armv6 and armv7 listed as Architectures. But still, I am geting the following errors:

1) iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture: At least one of the following architectures must be present: armv6

2) Application faild codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains dissallowed entitlements, or was not signed with and iPhone Distribution Certificate.

3) Unable to extract entitlements from application: (null)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much hunting and trying every common fix for code signing and entitlements issues, this seemed to work: Deleted armv6 from both Project and Target settings and changed OS Deplotment Target (in Target and Project) to 4.3 (or 5.0, both worked).

Subsequent times I've hit this snag, I've also found it especially useful to use the validate function before actually submitting. It can give you clues as to what is wrong that may not be included in the upload failed errors.